# How to access contacts only with email address in address book?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, contacts, addressbook

I am accessing all of the users contacts and emailing them through the app.  I can access all of the contacts fine, if they have an email address.  If they don't have an email address, then it gives me an error, I am trying to check if they have an email address before I attempt to add the address to the list of addresses.  I am using this code.  It gives me an error on the line of the if statement here: if ((ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, 0) != NULL))

How can I access only the contacts who have email addresses?

```
NSMutableArray* contactsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();


CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);
for (int i=0;i < nPeople;i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary* tempContactDic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);
    CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
    firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    [tempContactDic setValue:name forKey:@"name"];


    //fetch email id
    NSString *strEmail;
    ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);

    if ((ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, 0) != NULL))
    {

    CFStringRef tempEmailref = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, 0);
    strEmail = (__bridge  NSString *)tempEmailref;

    [contactsArray addObject:strEmail];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to check whether there are email address available by copying the first item in the array and check if the value is `NULL`. But if the array is empty you can't copy any items from it.

What you should do is check if the array holds any items:

```
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(email) > 0) {
    // There is at least one item in the email array/

}
```

Also be aware they your code only copies the first e-mail address for the contact, if more then 1 e-mail is set for that contact you might want to loop thru the e-mail array.

Answer (score 1):

U can use this code to fetch all emails of all users from your contacts.

```
- (void) getEmailsOfAllContacts
{
    ABAddressBookRef _addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray * allPeople = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBookRef);

    for (id record in allPeople)
    {        
        CFTypeRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonEmailProperty);

        NSArray * allEmailArray = ((__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty));

        NSString * email;

        for (int i = 0; i < [allEmailArray count]; i++)
        {
            email = [allEmailArray objectAtIndex: i];
            if (isEmpty(email) == NO)
            {
                [_allContactsEmailArray addObject: email];
            }
        }
    }

    CFRelease(_addressBookRef);
    allPeople = nil;
}
```